# Generate Parallel lines in Pixelmator

Tags: patterns, pixelmator

I need to generate parallel lines with gap of 18px in Pixelmator for the purpose of baseline. Is there any quick way like transform in Illustrator or pattern in PS? Is it possible to generate guides such way?

Answer (score 2):

with raster apps, I've always done it this way:

- Draw first line
- duplicated it and offset it the distance you want
- now draw a selection around both lines and duplicate these lines
- align one line from the original to the new one (you will now have 3 lines)
- duplicate the 3 to make 5, the 5 to make 9, the 9 to make 17, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If the lines are horizontal, vertical, or 45º diagonal, you can use the pen tool and press shift after the first point is placed.

Comment: I have to draw a set of lines (say 60) with equal distances apart.